# Basic topology & bevel help - How to fix beveling issue?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, bevel

I'm trying to model a hangboard and I'm having a hard time getting my bevel to work. Can someone explain to me how to correctly bevel the top edges of this? Below is a couple images of it, followed by my attempt.

[image: The Beastmaker 2000 Hangboard]
[image: The top edge is difficult to model for me]
[image: I'm trying to bevel the sloping parts at the top]

So my issue is the sloping parts on the top. I don't know how to correctly model them so that I can smoothly bevel them without artifacting. I don't know how else to block out the shape other than what I've done already. Obviously there are vertical faces whose edges meet at that top horizontal edge, but I don't know how to fix it. See my issue below:

[image: The edges of the sloping parts are interfering with each other]
[image: Unsure of how to workaround this]

Any advice is appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've reworked your topology to get a more clean bevel, Try this:

---

[image]
[image]

By adding a little bit of thickness to the back face, you can allow more room for the bevel to run before it overshoots. But keep in mind there will always be artifacts if you push the bevel too far on any kind of geometry.

If you want a thicker bevel and more control over the mesh, you can always take a subd approach. But for this piece I don't think it's necessary.

Here's the blend file with the reworked topology:

https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/D2ZXy03E/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much! Just for reference, what was your process? How bad was my original topology? I'm trying to understand where I went wrong, haha.

Comment: No problem. I used Boxcutter and HardOps to quickly boolean out the shapes, but it's not necessary as you can do the same in vanilla blender. Then I just added the bevel modifier and tweaked it. Your original file had some weird shading issues for some reason so I just started from scratch.